# psql ignores PGHOST and PGPORT variables

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql

I'm trying to change default port and host for psql. I added PGHOST and PGPORT to /etc/bash.bashrc and I can echo them and ping my remote `db_host` server:

```
$ echo $PGHOST
db_host
$ echo $PGPORT
19000
$ ping db_host
PING db_host (172.16.2.160) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from db_host (172.16.2.160): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.565 ms
64 bytes from db_host (172.16.2.160): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.925 ms
```

However, if I run psql I get a `could not connect to server` error.

```
$ psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Psql is trying to connect to my local instance and ignores PGHOST and PGPORT. Why doesn't psql pick up the variables?

If I specify port and host in command line like `psql -h $PGHOST -p $PGPORT`, psql can connect to my remote server.

P.S. I have Ubuntu Server 22.04 and Postgres 13 on local machine and on the remote side.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shell problem, not a database problem: you set the variables, but didn't `export` them so that they get passed to the environment of the `psql` process you start. Try

```bash
export PGHOST PGPORT
```

before calling `psql`.

Comment: Hi @Laurenz , they are already exported in bash.bashrc `export PGHOST='db_host '
export PGPORT='19000'`. I tried exporting them as you suggested right before `psql` calling but I got the same error, `psql` tries to connect to local instance `psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Comment: Perhaps you are not using `bash`?

Comment: I'm using bash `$ help` shows `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. I connect to the machine using ssh where I run `psql`. `echo` shows PGHOST and PGPORT variables even after server reboot. They are definitely exported but `psql` doesn't pick them up.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem. My `psql` command was added to /etc/super.tab. As soon it was removed, `psql` recognizes my env variable.